# How can I fix this handheld vacuum cleaner?

Tags: electrical, repair, battery

This is a handheld vacuum cleaner with a simple circuit inside. I’ve charged it fully for a good while and also tried decharge-recharging it but no joy. All it can manage to do is ticking the engine which is not powerful enough to get it on full rounds and working. I have contacted the producer and they said they don’t have batteries available for this item. Is there a way I could find out if it’s the battery or something else? I find it a waste to put this in the bin and buy a new one. [image: engine and batteries]

P. S. I have a video but it doesn’t seem like I can upload videos here.

Update:

Here’s how I’m testing it with the 9V battery:
[image: testing with 9v battery]

Update #2:
 I’m not sure if the contact is made but here’s how I’m testing and still no joy. I have a feeling that I’m making a mistake somewhere.

[image: testing]

Comment: Probably batteries. You could build your own. I did this to a wine bottle opener that lost its umph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Easy fix if it's the batteries**

The batteries are 18650s they are extremely common they are used in power tools, laptops, home devices and they are even the driving force behind the Tesla automobiles.

**Test**

Cut the red and black wires going to the batteries one at a time. Strip off a little bit of insulation and apply them to a 9 volt battery. Red+  black -

Leave the yellow wire for now. It senses the voltage for the charge indicator light. It's possibly connected to a chip wrapped in the battery casing.

**This is what the individual batteries look like**[image]

**CAUTION**

These batteries have a lot of kick. They are potentially very dangerous if the contacts are shorted. They will melt wire and are very capable of starting a fire.

If the unit runs on a 9v then the batteries need replacing. If that's the case you will need to order some Amazon has lots of them. You'll want to find some with the same mAh rating. In your case you will need two 1300mAh batteries.

**something like this, basically apply power directly to the motor.**

[image]

Comment: Do a bit of research on soldering leads to batteries -- it's not trivial. (Or, best case, buy batteries with tabs or leads already attached.) You want 'unprotected', as opposed to 'protected' batteries.

Comment: Would a 9V rectangular cube battery (whatever you call them!) work?

Comment: Yes exactly, only for testing purposes. A 9v cube will not last long running that motor. It will only tell you if the motor is good.

Comment: you can buy battery holder clips for 18650, just like those for AA, and you can even get them in different configs, like 2S, 2P, etc. A lot safer than wrongly soldering to batteries.

Comment: So I’m testing this with the 9v, but switching it on or off does nothing whatsoever. Could you take a look at the picture above please? I cut the metal plates that were soldered and placed them on the + and - terminals of the battery.

Comment: And to add further, I cut the plate from the yellow wire and contacted the ends to + and - on the battery and that turns the LED on, but no movement of the engine whatsoever.

Comment: You can try to bypass the controller and jumper directly to the motor. If the motor works then the controller is likely caput.

Comment: Can you explain how to do that a bit more? Bypass the controller?

Comment: Edit in the answer. Be careful as soon as you connect the wires, assuming the motor is good, it will start running. So leave one connection off and just brush it on the terminal.

Comment: Wow, thanks! See my update. There’s still no joy. Shall I cut the wires off the circuit board?! :-/

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the motor is dead. They are a lot harder to spec then a battery. If you have a tester you ohm out the motor. It's hard to say what resistance you "should" read but open line would confirm a dead motor. You would need to cut the leads or de-solder the leads for the motor off the board to properly test it.

Comment: and living at a consumerist world, it seems like way too much effort in comparison with 15-20 Euros that would cost me to buy a new one! Just a shame to trow the whole thing away, plus the disappointment of DIY project failing! :D Thanks for all the instructions.